# Are these routing rows redundant?

Tags: routing, router

Windows `route print`:

```
...
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
...
  192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.178    276
192.168.1.178  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.178    276
192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.178    276
...
```

What's the point of the last two rows? What happens when they are removed?

Doesn't the 3rd-last row already do what they do?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

They seem somewhat redundant but they represent different things.

192.168.1.0/24 is the route to the subnet, ie. 192.168.1.1 through 192.168.1.254

192.168.1.178/32 is the route to self, ie. loopback

192.168.1.255/32 is the route to the broadcast address, ie. to everyone on the subnet.

Comment: Do you mean that the last row is needed, but the 2nd-last row is redundant? If I remove the last row, does 192.168.1.255 then default to the default gateway?

Comment: I'm not sure how Windows handles that, but by the book, the host would try to ARP 192.168.1.255 since the subnet entry fits.